# Discrete math: Sum of Geometric series on a problem - Notes make little sense.

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

I've been reading a PDF of slides from my Discrete Math I professor. The title is Sums, Products and Asymptotic Estimations.

He gives us a problem to fire off the lecture, which is the following:

```
In a TV game show, the host is willing to give you 50,000€ every year for 20
years, or 750,000€ right in your hands. 

What would be the most profitable choice, if you knew that the interest rate
in the bank is 3% every year?
```

He then goes on, in the notes, and says that the total value of per-year reward is $\sum\limits_{i=0}^{19}\frac{50000}{(i+p)^i}$

Right after that, to calculate the sum, he's got a slide titled "Summation of geometrical series", in which he writes: 
$\begin{split}
S(k) & = x^0 + x^1 + ... + x^k \\
-xS(k) & = -x^1 - x^2 - ... - x^{k+1} \\
S(k) - xS(k) & = 1 - x^{k+1} \Rightarrow S(k) = \frac{1-x^{k+1}}{1-x}
\end{split}$

Finally, he finishes by referencing the problem again, this time saying

```
As we calculated, it is more profitable to get 50,000€ for 20 years
as it has a value of 766,190.
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction or assist me in finding out how he came to that conclusion?

I cannot, for the life of me, understand how he ended up with that result. Isn't $x$ here supposed to be $\frac{1}{1.03^i}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The details depend on whether we get the first $50000$ right now, or a year from now. We will assume right now.

We need to calculate the **present value** (PV) of $50000$ that we get $k$ years from today. This is the amount $A_k$ which if invested would grow to $50000$ in $k$ years.

Now $A_k$, in $k$ years, grows to $A_k(1.03)^k$. If this is $50000$, then $A_k=50000(1.03)^{-k}$. So the present value of the $20$ payments is
$$50000+50000(1.03)^{-1}+50000(1.03)^{-2}+\cdots +50000(1.03)^{-19}.$$

To calculate, we need to find the sum of the geometric series
$$1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{19},$$
where $x=(1.03)^{-1}$.
To find a formula for the sum, let $S=1+x+x^2+\cdots +x^{19}$. Then $xS=x+x^2+x^3+\cdots +x^{20}$. Subtract. There is a lot of cancellation. We get
$$S-xS=(1-x)S=1-x^{20},$$
which gives us
$$S=\frac{1-x^{20}}{1-x}.$$
The rest is calculator work. Plug in $(1.03)^{-1}$ for $x$, and multiply by $50000$.

Comment: Why are you dividing the yearly "gains" by something larger than 1? That's what I don't really understand. Shouldn't the individual elements for every k>0 be larger than 50000?

Comment: Oops, forgot to also thank you for your complete/elaborate answer!

Comment: The answer above contains a brief justification. More informally, the (present) value of the $50000$ that we will get $7$ years from today is **less** than $50000$. It is the amount (which I called $A_7$ in the answer) which if invested today would grow to $50000$ in $7$ years. That's why the $50000$ that we get $7$ years from now has present value of only $\frac{50000}{(1.03)^7}$.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: You are welcome. The concept of present value is very useful. In order to compare amounts received at different times, we need to "bring them" to the same moment. To bring money forward in time, multiply by $(1+r)^k$. To bring it backwards, divide by $(1+r)^k$.